# margin-top applies to sibling element also

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations, margin

I am creating an **About** page for my website. I have one parent element called `maindiv`, a flexbox with two children, one is `leftcont` and another is `rightcont`. I want to create an animation using margin-top to `leftcont`.
But when I do the same, the animation is being applied to its sibling(`rightcont`) div also which I do not want

Can you please help me with the same
Here is the code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      .imganim {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        border: 2px solid red;
        transition: 2s;
      }

      .maindiv {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }

      .leftcont {
        width: 50%;
        border: 2px solid red;
      }

      .rightcont {
        width: 50%;
        animation: none;
        border: 2px solid black;
        margin-top: 0 !important;
      }

      .marginanim {
        animation: margin 2.4s infinite;
      }

      @keyframes margin {
        0% {
          margin-top: 0;
        }

        50% {
          margin-top: 10px;
        }

        100% {
          margin-top: 0;
        }
      }
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="maindiv">
      <div class="leftcont marginanim">
        <img
          src="https://solutionfest.netlify.app/static/media/vector8.5596c5d75a5f1c4454c0.jpg"
          alt=""
        />
      </div>
      <div class="rightcont">
        <h2>Aboutme</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi,
          obcaecati similique? Eligendi sint, laborum aspernatur, temporibus
          consequuntur ipsa officiis, praesentium distinctio necessitatibus sed
          debitis eius facilis molestiae. Consectetur laboriosam veritatis quis
          perspiciatis ab quae sunt nam itaque veniam mollitia obcaecati non
          minima molestias illo cum, ducimus soluta modi inventore consequuntur.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Probably the effect of _collapsing margins_. Do not move the element by animating margin-top, but `transform: translateY(...)` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`margin-top` also changes the size of the parent, and this also affects the `rightcont`. If you use `transform: translateY` property the parent does not notice the movement and you get the effect you are looking for.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.imganim {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  transition: 2s;
}

.maindiv {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.leftcont {
  width: 50%;
  border: 2px solid red;
  
  z-index:0;
}

.rightcont {
  width: 50%;
  animation: none;
  border: 2px solid black;
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  
  z-index:1;
}

.marginanim {
  animation: margin 2.4s infinite;
}

@keyframes margin {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateY(10px);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="maindiv">
  <div class="leftcont marginanim">
    <img src="https://solutionfest.netlify.app/static/media/vector8.5596c5d75a5f1c4454c0.jpg" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="rightcont">
    <h2>Aboutme</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Animi, obcaecati similique? Eligendi sint, laborum aspernatur, temporibus consequuntur ipsa officiis, praesentium distinctio necessitatibus sed debitis eius facilis molestiae. Consectetur laboriosam
      veritatis quis perspiciatis ab quae sunt nam itaque veniam mollitia obcaecati non minima molestias illo cum, ducimus soluta modi inventore consequuntur.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```